# what does the negative margin do to set the element in the center of the page?

Tags: html, css

I came across the following *css* snippet. It gives an element with id *search bar* the absolute position,a width of `300px`,height of 27px and it sets the search bar `50%` from it's normal position

```
#search_bar {
  position:relative;
  width: 300px;
  left:50%;
  height:27px;
}
```

But I don't see the *search bar* aligned in the center. Why is that ? But if I change the snippet to :

```
#search_bar {
  position:relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left:-150px;
  left:50%;
  height:27px;
}
```

it gets aligned to the center of the page. How is that ? What does the property `margin-left:-150px` do to set it to the center ?

Comment: It would be better to center something like this with margin auto and remove the left property http://jsfiddle.net/C3jm4/1/. Mr. Alien explains it best how your example css is working. The advantage with the method I showed here is that the width can be dynamic and unknown and the element will still be centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using position absolute so the negative margin is half of the width of the element so that it shifts the element behind by 1/2 of it's total width

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%; /* This shifts the element 50% from left, if you 
             don't want to use negative margins you can use 45%, 40% but you need 
             to fiddle with the measurements first */
```

[image]

So the calculation goes like

Total Container Width `1000px`

Element Width `300px`

left: `50%` means it will start from left `500px` to `800px`

So this is not centered yea?

So `-150px` from `500px` /* 500 here is left: 50% */

You get element from `350px` to `650px`

Answer (score 2):

left: 50% puts the beginning of the bar at the middle of the screen, which isn't centered.  However, if you know the width of the bar (300px), then move it left half of that, then the middle of the bar will be in the middle of the screen.  Does that make sense?  150 is half of the 300 width.  If the bar was 400 width, then you would need to use -200.

Answer (score 0):

By using relative positioning, you're allowing movement of the block relative to where it would be if it was `static`.  `left: 50%` places the left side of the margin half way across the containing positioned block which for you is probably the viewport (aka the browser window).  `margin-left: -150px` will then move the left side of the margin box to the left 150px from the current position margin box.  Since your total width is 300px, this makes it so that the border/content box is centered relative to the containing positioned block.